# A short note on the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I want to put this note on my bibliography. Preferably between the heading and the \bibitems. How can I do that?

```
\noindent On long term, articles that are published merely as web pages can be
          accessed via the ``way back machine'' of           
          \url{http://www.archive.org}}
```

Answer (score 5):

For the standard document classes, you can redefine `\thebibliography`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\let\theOLDbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{\theOLDbibliography{#1}%
  \item[]\noindent On long term, articles that are published merely as web pages can be
          accessed via the ``way back machine'' of           
          \url{http://www.archive.org}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{one} First bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The classes of the KOMA-Script bunddle offer the `\setbibpreamble` which implements this feature. The memoir document class offer the analogous `\prebibhook` command.

Comment: This is a great and useful answer. Only, would it be possible to have the note span the whole width of the text, rather than being left aligned with the bibliography items (i.e., leaving space for the non-existent number)?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to do it using biblatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\defbibnote{mynote}{On long term, articles that are published merely as web pages can be
    accessed via the ``way back machine'' of \url{http://www.archive.org}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[prenote=mynote]

\end{document}
```